# How to apply a Codemirror mode in this React + Browserify environment

Tags: reactjs, browserify, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I'm developping an app based on this boilerplate: [react-app-boilerplate](https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-app-boilerplate)

I'm using the [react-codemirror module](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-codemirror)

I want to apply the javascript mode to codemirror but I get a 'CodeMirror is undefined' error when symply inserting the external script found at http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js

I'm unsure how to pipe everything together in this configuration, I have tried to require the CodeMirror object from react-codemirror in the javascript.js file but wasn't successful.

```
var InputCode = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      code: '{ "message": "Some JSON input" }'
    };
  },
  updateCode (newCode) {
    this.setState({
      code: newCode
    });
  },
  render () {
    var options = {
      lineNumbers: true,
      extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
      mode: {name: "javascript", json: true, globalVars: true},
      theme: "sublime-text-like",
      viewportMargin: Infinity
    };
    return <Codemirror value={this.state.code} onChange={this.updateCode} options={options} />;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please check out [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) for usage with React. `defineMode` is supported!

Answer (score 2):

Require all the CodeMirror modes and addons you need up-front - when you require them, they use `CodeMirror.defineMode()` to configure themselves, so they'll be found when CodeMirror tries to use them later on.

e.g. for the boilerplate you're using, require the JavaScript mode in its `main.js` module before rendering your app:

```
require('codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript')
```